# list of files and folder in a specific way using command prompt

Tags: cmd

I need list of files and folders in a directory **(Note:no sub folder files)** using command prompt ,in the  format ie. *File name - size - file type*.
I tried using `dir /A/S >AllFiles.txt`. But the output is in a format that needs editing.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with only the "dir" command. Powershell's get-childitem will do the trick though.

```
get-childitem -recurse | Select-Object basename, length, extension
```

Assuming you are running from cmd you could wrap the above powershell command line this:

```
powershell -Command  "get-childitem -recurse | Select-Object basename, length, extension"
```

To see all available options for the Select-Object clause you can run

```
get-childitem | get-member
```

in the powershell

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by file type. I'll assume you mean the file extension.

There isn't a simple way to get the total size of a folder, so I will list folders as `name - <dir>`.

The `-` is valid in file and folder names. You might be better off substituting `:` instead.

The simple FOR command lists either files, or folders, but not both. So below I use two FOR commands. The advantage of this is it supports unicode in names.

```
@echo off
(
  for %%F in (*) do echo %%F - %%~zF - %%~xF
  for /d %%F in (*) do echo %%F - ^<dir^>
)>AllFiles.txt
```

You can combine DIR /B with FOR /F to get both files and folders in one pass, but it does not support unicode in the names.

```
@echo off
(
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b') do (
    if exist "%%F\" (echo %%F - ^<dir^>) else (echo %%F - %%~zF - %%~xF)
  )
)>AllFiles.txt
```